# Array to string issue , PHP

Tags: php, html, sql, web

I'm working on a comment system, pretty basic at the moment.  I'm encountering an error when trying to obtain the comment from the database.

The curiosity for me is that this is almost identical code to what I used on a similar page and no error then, however...

The flow is

HTML FORM:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?id=".$id?>" id="addComment" class="form-horizontal">
<textarea class="span10" name="comment" id="comment" rows="3" class="required"></textarea>
<button type="submit" name="addComment" id="addComment" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Add Comment</button>
</form>
```

TOP OF PAGE FOR PHP:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

//have id already
$name = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$comment = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']));

$articleComments->addComment($id, $name, $comment);

}
?>
```

The Function:

```
//add comment to an article(check ip for bans(later))
public function addComment($articleId, $name, $comment){

    $query = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO `articleComments`
                (`articleId`,`name`,`date`,`comment`)
                VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
    $date = date ("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
    $query->bindValue(1, $articleId);
    $query->bindValue(2, $name);
    $query->bindValue(3, $date);
    $query->bindValue(4, $comment);

    try{
        $query->execute();
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getCode());
    }
}
```

and then the output function:

```
    //get all comments
public function getAllComments($aticleId){

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `articleComments` WHERE `articleId` = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1,$aticleId);

    try{
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll();
    }catch (PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

followed by the output:

```
$comments = $articleComments->getAllComments($id);

foreach ($comments as $c){

  $commentId = $c['id'];
  $name = $c['name'];
  $date = $c['date'];
  $comm = $c['comment'];
  $like = $c['likes'];
  //echo "Name: " . $name;
  //echo "  Date: " . $date;
  echo $comments;    
 }
```

The name and id etc all comes out ok.  but I get `**Notice: Array to string conversion in bla**` and nothing output when asking for the comment. I've dumped the variable and it's definitely there, I'm just not sure how to get it or why it's not working like I expect it to.

I tried changing the db to varchar as well (as a noob test) and same result.

Comment: The problem is that For $comments array, you are treating it like a string & prints. I guess it's $comm! Just Check.

Answer (score 2):

The "blabla" you mentioned should be your biggest clue on where to look for a problem. It tells you exactly in this line the error occurred - so look at this line.

See this:

```
echo $comments;
```

I assume you wanted to do this instead:

```
echo $comm;
```

`$comments` is an array, you assign the text of the comment to `$comm`.

Comment: +1 Didn't actually see that line due to the question formatting